Solution of $X^2+3Y^2=4m$
Choose $m\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ such that $m$ is not square and $3\nmid m$.
Consider the integer solutions of the equation $X^2+3Y^2=4m$.
I observed that $\sum\limits_{}(X^2-2m)=0$, where summation runs over all $X$ satisfying above equation.
For example, assume that $m=7$. Then, the possible value for $X^2$ is $1,16,25$.
Thus we have $(1-14)+(16-14)+(25-14)=-13+2+11=0$.
Assume that $m=13$. Then, the possible value for $X^2$ is $4,25,49$.
Thus we have $(4-26)+(25-26)+(49-26)=-22-1+23=0$.
I guess that this holds for all $m$. Is there any method to prove this?

It doesn't work for $m=1$

@jjagmath I'm sorry. I add the condition that $m$ is not square.

@jjagmath It works if you count the solutions by $(X,Y)$ values: $(-2,0), (-1,-1), (-1,1), (1,-1), (1,1), (2,0)$ resulting in $(4-2) + (1-2) + (1-2) + (1-2) +(1-2) + (4-2) = 0$.

@RobertIsrael That's right. It seems to hold for square case. Thank you.

It also seems to hold when $m$ is divisible by $3$. In fact a solution for any $m$ can be mapped to one fir $m$ three times as large through a mulriplication with Eisenstein integers, and the multiplication will not alster the homogeneous condition in the sum.

We may render the following:
$4(x^2+3y^2)=(x^2+9y^2)+3(x^2+y^2)$
$=(x^2-6xy+9y^2)+3(x^2+2xy+y^2)$
$=(x-3y)^2+3(x+y)^2$
So if $(x,y)$ is a solution for a given $m$ so is $(\frac12(x-3y),\frac12(x+y))$.
We then iterate this transformation and find that it cycles through a finite set of solutions:
$(x,y)\to(\frac12(x-3y),\frac12(x+y))\to(\frac12(-x-3y),\frac12(x-y))\to(-x,-y)$
where $(-x,-y)$ then transforms into the additive inverses of the second and third solutions then back to $(x,y)$. We thus have a cycle of six solutions with three distinct values of the square of the first coordinate. If these three squares add up to $3×2m=6m$, the claim will be proved.
Thus
$x^2+\frac14(x-3y)^2+\frac14(x+3y)^2=\frac32x^2+\frac32y^2=\frac32×4m=6m☆$
Note: The proof counts separate solutions in the sum, and this is where the equality applies. No step in the proof requires specifically $3\not| m$. Plugging in $m=3$ as a trial shows that the claim holds, so apparently the constraint $3\not| m$ can be dropped.

Thank you for nice answer! Your help was invaluable in solving the problem. May I cite your solution in my paper?

Go ahead, you can cite it. Please acknowledge the source.
